# hall way lighting switch position

Tags: lighting

this could just me being fussy but I have a 3 way switch for outside light, kitchen and hall and then a second switch for hall and loft. Since I've moved in the hall way switches are always opposite, so 3 way will be on and the 2 way will be off. Is there any way that I can fix it so if the light is off, both switches are off for example.

Sorry for being fussy! 
Pug

Comment: Pull the screws and turn the switch over.

Comment: But then the loft switch would be upside down

Comment: purchase a digital model that you tap to turn on and off then there is no fixed position that standard 3 way switches have.